# Convert BBCode [url] tags into clickable HTML <a href> links

Tags: php, replace, text-parsing, bbcode

I was using `str_replace()` for other BBCodes, but I'm stuck with the `url` portion.

I need to convert:

```
[url=http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&q=brits+pub&near=Pasadena,+CA&fb=1&cid=0,0,17926180203917841249&sa=X&oi=local_result&resnum=1&ct=image]Brits[/url]
```

to

```
<a href="ttp://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&q=brits+pub&near=Pasadena,+CA&fb=1&cid=0,0,17926180203917841249&sa=X&oi=local_result&resnum=1&ct=image">Brits</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you take a look at other [BBCode parsers](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+bbcode+parser)?

Just replacing tags isn't sufficient anyways, since this can (and will) lead to incorrect markup.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a good SO question about this already: [Best way to parse bbcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode).

Also, using an [already existing BBCode parser library](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser) is advisable to attempting to making your own.

Comment: @Franz - could you clarify: are you talking about a specific case? or are you saying this doesn't parse correctly?

Comment: You edited your answer. Still: incorrectly nested tags? `[b][i][/b][/i]`