# How to Create Hyper Link from User Defined Tag Using Regular Expression

Tags: php, replace, bbcode

How can I create a hyper link from following string.

```
[url =http://google.com] Google [/url]
```

it should be replaced with

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

The anchor tag is structured with the url as the src attribute and the center as a caption

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse bbcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode)

Comment: That post is tagged cakePHP also. I think considering Raw PHP, this post can stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are writing bbcode.  If so writing an actual parser would be faster but if you just want to do search and replace something like

```
preg_replace('/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i', '<a href='.$1.'>'.$2.'</img>');
```

I cannot remember the jsfiddle like site that lets you show regexp so if someone know it please leave it in the comments.

Also if you are gonna just copy and paste my code into your bbcode seach and replace file... DONT it's vulnerable to xss injection and really not an amazing expression it just is an example.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you would want to use is [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: I don't see where you're going with that