# Regex to remove all occurances of string only within tags

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all occurances of a string but only when it is within 2 tags.

For example in the content below I need to remove both occurances of foo within the [bar][/bar] tags.

```
foo
foo
[bar]
foo bar foo
[/bar]
foo
```

I am using PHP and I would like to find a solution which doesn't involve 2 steps (ie search for the content between [bar][/bar] first and then do the replace). If this is not possible then no problem, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are there nested tags? can there be accidentally left open tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse bbcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode)

Comment: For the purposes of this I'm not worried about tags left open or a scenario where there is `[bar][bar]foo[/bar][/bar]`.

Comment: Im also not trying to do any parsing, I just want to remove a string - the BBCode syntax is coincidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tags are all well formed and not nested you may be successful with this

```
\bfoo\b(?=[^\[]*\[\/bar\])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uccj)

It searches for `foo` surrounded by word boundaries `\b` (foo in foobar will not match), that is followed by a closing tag `[/bar]`. to ensure that there is no new opening tag I will only match characters other than `[` with `[^\[]*`.

`(?=[^\[]*\[\/bar\])` is a lookahead assertion that does not match it only looks ahead if the pattern inside is following.

Comment: Very clever thanks... didn't think about only matching the end tag.