# php regex [b] to <b>

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

```
  "'\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]'is",
```

Is my current RegEx working. But I want to change the [] to be <> instead. But it doesn't work... What more then just the [] do I need to change.

Comment: Can you post some of the text your are trying to replace and what you'd like the output to be?

Comment: One advice, don't do it this way - you can get something like "<b>lorem<i>ipsum</b>ipsum</i>", if you parse multiple tags. Don't use regexp to parse BBCode or anything else that is a markup language - parse it char by char or you will get invalid results.

Comment: +1 to @Griwes comment. There are myriad solutions (including PECL and PEAR libraries) that will do the job for you, with much more success than hacking about with regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse bbcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode)

Comment: If you're going to use a posting pseudolanguage, you should be tokenizing the data instead of storing raw HTML.  (Basically, you store it in a half-parsed state.)

Comment: Finding a simple lib to parse BBcode is as easy as type it in google. You could check my implementation of template parser - it would require few changes to fit bbcode, but you can learn something from it. There _are_ code duplicates, but it is old forgotten project ;) [Grab it here](http://code.google.com/p/qfw/source/browse/trunk/php/lib/templates/template.class.php)

Comment: @Griwes Regexes parse char by char. He just doing it wrong. But yes, a pattern that validates/parses valid markup will correctly fail to do so on invalid markup.

Comment: @tchrist, I don't get your point here, in: first, reviving old question, second, saying that I am right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [various BBCode parsers](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=bbcode&in=packages&x=0&y=0) available for PHP, for instance

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

which allows you to simply define your replacement rules by hand:

```
echo bbcode_parse(
    bbcode_create(
        array(
            'b' => array(
                'type'      => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
                'open_tag'  => '<b>',
                'close_tag' => '</b>'
            )
        )
    ),
    '[b]Bold Text[/b]'
);
// prints <b>Bold Text</b>
```

Also check the various similar questions about BBCode Parsers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bbcode+php

Answer (score 1):

Try `~` as a delimiter instead

```
preg_match("~<b>(.*?)</b>~is", $text, $b);
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. So `'` is perfectly valid as a delimiter.