# markitup and Php BBCode Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing

I downloaded the markitup and followed their instructions and downloaded the BBcode parser 
(called Recruiting Parser).

In the documentation it said to support only a few of the code tags and it seems that it doesn't support others e.g. `[code][/code]`.

```
require_once("parser.php");
```

When I do this:

```
$parser = new parser;
$parsed = $parser->p($threadContent);
```

I get some but not all code tags transferred to HTML. `[list]` and `[preview]` for example don't.

Is there a better parser that will transfer all the tags, to HTML mark up?

Comment: For the love of God, please don't use BBCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788959/regex-to-split-bbcode-into-pieces/3792262#3792262

Comment: [PHP has a native BBCode Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545920/php-regex-b-to-b/7546030#7546030)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to Parse BBCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode)

Comment: any idea how can I use the preview button, cause it isnt working now

Comment: @NullUserException, BBcodes are very well known and do their job just fine. So why should we refuse them?

Comment: @user2513149 They are a bad choice for the reasons I explained in my post. Continuing to use them just because they are "established" is not a good argument.