# How can I make this BBcode? [HTML to PHP]

Tags: php, html, bbcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex <b> to <b>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545920/php-regex-b-to-b)

Inside my admin panel I have a textarea where staff can insert messages to customers.

I want to convert and detect `[[p=304_red]]` to two matches within a return. I was thinking str_replace but I cannot do it twice. Also, str_replace would be limited to one, a staff member might add it twice. Anyone recommend a better solution (preg_replace seem tricky and messy)

```
[[p=304_red]]
```

Should return

```
<a href="http://site.com/jump?go=304_red">
<img src="http://cdn.com/304_red/large/1.jpg" />
</a>
```

My code only returns the URL.

```
$question = $_GET['replyBoxField'];
$question = str_replace("[[p=", "<a href='http://site.com/jump?go='>", $question);
$question = str_replace("]]", "</a>", $question);
```

Comment: You need to some how make a loop that stores all the productId in strings and then you can re use as an many times as you want..

Comment: @AlphaApp Yes exactly. Can you show me an example?

Comment: `str_replace` is not limited to "one", and I explicitly mean the two types of "one" that are possible. So what is your question?

Comment: This was not a duplicate so why the downvote and closing. Bloats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple regex should work for you here.

```
$question = preg_replace('@\[\[p=([^\]]+)\]\]@i', '<a href="http://site.com/jump?go=$1"><img src= "http://cdn.com/$1/large/1.jpg" ></a>', $question);
```

=)

Comment: You were faster than me, and I think your regex works better than mine. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thanks, yours was pretty much the same, just 30 seconds later =P

Answer (score 0):

Isn't regex a better approach?

```
$filter = "/\[\[p=([^\]\s]+)\]\]/";
$transform = "<a href='http://site.com/jump?go=$1'><img src='http://cdn.com/$1/large/1.jpg' /></a>";

$string = preg_replace($filter, $transform, $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

All other answers wrong, see this:

Change your BBCode to this `[[p=304_sapphire]#[304_sapphire]]`

```
$question = str_replace("[[p=", "<a href='http://domain.com/jump?go=", $question);
$question = str_replace("]#[", "'><img src='http://cdn.com/files/", $question);
$question = str_replace("]]", "/1/small.jpg'/></a>", $question);
```

Comment: This is redundant. The user shouldn't be forced to enter the same info twice.

Comment: Agree, thanks for the effort but -1 I wanted one.