# How to remove surrounding Square Brackets using php

Tags: php

I need a way to remove the surrounding square brackets from this using only php:

```
[txt]text[/txt]
```

So the result should be: text

They will always occur in matched pairs.

They always will be at the start and end of the string. Thet will always be [txt1][/txt1] or [url2][/url2]

How can i do it?

Comment: Will the square brackets always occur in matched pairs ([thing]...[/thing]?) Will they always be at the start and end of the string? Might they be nested? Might they be improperly nested ([thing1]...[thing2]...[/thing1]...[/thing2])? What should happen if they are?

Comment: @Hammerite Yes, they will always occur in matched pairs. They always will be at the start and end of the string. Thet will always be [thing1][/thing1] or [thing2][/thing2]

Comment: are you looking for a [bbcode parser](http://php.net/bbcode)? If so then possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545920

Comment: @Gordon Something like it but I just need this specific part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/\[(\/\s*)?txt\d*\]/i", "", "[txt]text[/txt]");
```

**Update:**

This will work for "whatever" in the brackets:

```
preg_replace("/\[.+?\]/i", "", "[txt]text[/txt]");
```

Comment: Yes but this will only work with txt not with what ever is within the brackets.

Comment: How can I make it to work with what ever it is within the brackets? Thanks.

Comment: @JoseCardama, please see the updated answer.  That will match and remove whatever is in the brackets.  But note that this will also remove any such tags that are not in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
$string = '[whatever]content[/whatever]';
$pattern = '/\[[^\[\]]*\]/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

This will remove all `[whatever]` from a string.

Comment: My bad, I made a typo in the regex. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use regexp. You can explode the string on first ], after that use the result to explode on [.

Advantage using this method is that it is fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to get the text between square brackets of a simple structure, then try this:

```
$str = '[tag1]fdhfjdkf dfhjdkf[/tag1]';
$start_position = strpos($str, ']') + 1;
$end_postion = strrpos($str, '[');
$cleared = substr($str, $start_position, $end_postion - $start_position);
```

For more complicated structures this code won't work and you'll have to use some other ways.