# Show bbcode in html page with php

Tags: php, bbcode

I already a bbcode string `$mybbcode = [b]Hello word[/b]`
 with php i want to show it with html format in html page. 
ex: <`div><b>hello word</b><div>`

Comment: Dear `preg_replace`is what you need, see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) or a BBcode parsing library, see [here](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regex \[b\] to <b>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545920/php-regex-b-to-b)

Comment: See http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically that others already said to you after, but if you search in Google you'll see quicky lot of info about that, and done functions. Here is a sample:

```
function bbc2html($content) {
  $search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
    '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[url\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/'
  );

  $replace = array (
    '<strong>$2</strong>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>'
  );

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
```

Only for lazy programmers ;)

I invite you to search and decide what are the best from all code already done for you project.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use regex to convert BBCodes to HTML : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

For example :

```
$string = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]#iUs', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```