# Echo an image tag with site_url() inside PHP tags

Tags: php, html

I have a loop in my view that outputs all the content gathered from the database:

```
<?php foreach($content as $contentRow): ?>
     <?php
          echo $contentRow->value; 
     ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works fine for HTML strings like:

```
<h2><strong>Example Text</strong></h2>
```

however I have some image content that I would like to display and I have tried the following database entries to no avail:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('pathToImage/Image.png'); ?>" alt="Cover">"
<img src="site_url('pathToImage/Image.png')" alt="Cover\">"
```

I feel like I am missing a step on how to use PHP values in this way.

How do I access the URL of the image and use that to show the image?

---

Full Code Edit

```
<?php
    $CI =& get_instance();
?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-20">
                <!--<form class="form-center" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" role="form">-->
<!--                    <h2 class="">Title</h2>
                    <h2 class=""SubTitle/h2>-->
                    <?php echo $this->session->userdata('someValue'); ?>

                    <!--//<table class="" id="">-->

                        <?php foreach($content as $contentRow): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php
                            echo $contentRow->value; 
                            ?></td>                            
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <!--</table>-->

                <!--</form>-->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

and the values are being read out in `$contentRow->value;`

Comment: `<?php echo site_url('pathToImage/Image.png'); ?>` whats wrong in this ?

Comment: @devpro The output apparently (see line below)

Comment: If I put that then that string is simply echo'd. I think it's because it's a PHP tag inside a PHP tag

Comment: put your complete code

Comment: Are you storing the image titles database side or simply just fetching from a folder?

Comment: Show us the code around the line you mention. You are right its probably because its php tagged inside a php tag. This looks like `Wordpress-ade-gook` code

Comment: @Option Just fetching from a folder (assets/images)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in an `eval()`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The php tag is inside a string from the database

Comment: Full View code added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to verify this, but to me it looks like you are echo'ing a string with a PHP function. The function `site_url()` is not executed, but simply displayed. You can execute it by running the `eval()` function. But I have to add this function can be very dangerous and its use is not recommended.

**Update:**
To sum up some comments: The use of eval() is discouraged! You should reconsider / rethink your design. Maybe the use of tags which are replaced by HTML are a solution (Thanks to  Manfred Radlwimmer). Always keep in mind to never trust the data you display, always filter and check!

Comment: I agree - storing code in a database and executing it sounds like a perfect entry point for potential exploits.

Comment: So am I just completly missing a design paradigm/pattern that I should be following? (although I'm aware this question-addendum isn't really in the remit of SO)

Comment: I would say you have designed yourself into a nasty dark corner

Comment: Any idea what would happen when you `eval()` the normal bits of data like `eval('<h2><strong>Example Text</strong></h2>')` I have never used it so I have no idea!

Comment: **EVAL()** Form the manual _Caution

The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand._

Comment: @RiggsFolly It would fail because eval doesn't like raw html and certainly can handle additional `<?php` tags

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Then this answer is a LONG WAY from a good one

Comment: _Rule of Thumb_ If `eval()` seems like the answer ___You are asking the wrong question___

Comment: @RiggsFolly It captures the essentials: 1.) How could it be done 2.) Why you shouldn't do it like this. An answer that fixes this problem the way GPPK wants it would actually be counter-productive.

Comment: That is correct, maybe I should not suggest the use of `eval()`. Some might think it is a viable solution...

Comment: @GPPK you could use/build something similar to PhpBB - a small subset of allowed tags (e.g. `[img]`, `[a]`, etc.) that get interpreted and replaced with HTML

Comment: You mean like my content_type column in my database? Some days I feel like an idiot. Today is one...

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Is on to something. But that means your simple foreach loop is going to need to do a lot of checking before doing anything, and the likelyhood is you will think you got it sorted and something else will bite you in the rear

Comment: @GPPK Example: You store `[img]Image.png[/img] [a]google.com additional [b]text[/b][/a]` in your database, interpret it in php and echo out `<img src="/img/Image.png/"> <a href="http://google.com">additional <b>text</b></a>` You just need to find/write an interpreter (e.g. something [like this](http://www.bbcode-to-html.com/)).

Comment: Found an easy one here on SO: [Show bbcode in html page with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200048/show-bbcode-in-html-page-with-php). Actually there are a lot more, simply google `BBCode PHP`

Comment: Thanks @PhilippPalmtag And all, I've added my solution as a new answer. But with your help we got there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to accept this answer as @Philipp Palmtag's answer helped me out alot more and this is more supplementary information.

Because I'm reading data from the database it seems a sensible place to leave some information about what content is stored. In the same table that the content is stored I have added a "content type" field.

In my view I can then read this content type and render appropriately for the content that is stored. If it is just text I can leave it as HTML markup, images all I need to do is specify the file path and then I can scale this as I see fit.

I have updated my view to something akin to this and the if/else statement can be added to in the future if required:

```
<?php foreach($content as $contentRow): ?>
   <?php if ($contentRow->type != "image"): ?>
      <?php echo $contentRow->value; ?>    
   <?php else: ?>
      <?php echo "<img src=\"".site_url($contentRow->value)."\">"; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```