# Forum isn't following the BBcode

Tags: php

My forum isn't following the bbcode. Apostorphies and breaks especially aren't working. 
I know it's not an issue with the include, because my smileys page works fine. It's just this page.

Also, nl2br isn't working either.

Can someone tell me if my code looks correct?

```
<?
function forumbb($content){ //define the function of bbcode 
$content = nl2br($content); //replaces returns with br's 
$match = array( 
'#\[sup\]#se', 
'#\[\/sup\]#se', 
'#rnrn#se', 
'#\[p\]#se', 
'#\[\/p\]#se', 
'#\[br\]#se', 
'#\[\br\]#se', 
'#\[b\]#se', 
'#\[\/b\]#se', 
'#\[i\]#se', 
'#\[\/i\]#se', 
'#\[u\]#se', 
'#\[\/u\]#se', 
'#\[left\]#se', 
'#\[\/left\]#se', 
'#\[right\]#se', 
'#\[\/right\]#se', 
'#\[center\]#se', 
'#\[\/center\]#se', 
'#\[\/font\]#se', 
'#\[fontc\=(.*?)s\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontc\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)s\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fonts\=(.*?)c\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fonts\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)c\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontf\=(.*?)c\=(.*?)s\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontf\=(.*?)s\=(.*?)c\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontc\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontc\=(.*?)s\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fonts\=(.*?)f\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fonts\=(.*?)c\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fonts\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontf\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[fontc\=(.*?)\]#se', 
'#\[#se', 
'#\]#se', 
'#neoHTML#se', 
'#\*acara\*#se', 
'#\*aisha\*#se', 
'#\*blumaroo\*#se', 
'#\*bori\*#se', 
'#\*bruce\*#se', 
'#\*buzz\*#se', 
'#\*chia\*#se', 
'#\*cybunny\*#se', 
'#\*draik\*#se', 
'#\*eyrie\*#se', 
'#\*flotsam\*#se', 
'#\*gelert\*#se', 
'#\*gnorbu\*#se', 
'#\*grundo\*#se', 
'#\*hissi\*#se', 
'#\*jubjub\*#se', 
'#\*kacheek\*#se', 
'#\*kau\*#se', 
'#\*kiko\*#se', 
'#\*korbat\*#se', 
'#\*kougra\*#se', 
'#\*krawk\*#se', 
'#\*kyrii\*#se', 
'#\*lenny\*#se', 
'#\*lupe\*#se', 
'#\*SketchedNeo\*#se', 
'#\*meerca\*#se', 
'#\*ogrin\*#se', 
'#\*poogle\*#se', 
'#\*pteri\*#se', 
'#\*ruki\*#se', 
'#\*scorchio\*#se', 
'#\*shoyru\*#se', 
'#\*techo\*#se', 
'#\*tonu\*#se', 
'#\*usul\*#se', 
'#\*wocky\*#se', 
'#\*xweetok\*#se', 
'#\*yurble\*#se', 
'#\*zafara\*#se', 
'#\*candycane\*#se', 
'#\*aaa\*#se',
'#\*abigail\*#se',
'#\*boatswain\*#se',
'#\*cabinboy\*#se',
'#\*coltzan\*#se',
'#\*cook\*#se',
'#\*gunner\*#se',
'#\*hanso\*#se',
'#\*happiness\*#se',
'#\*illusen\*#se',
'#\*jazan\*#se',
'#\*jhudora\*#se',
'#\*lulu\*#se',
'#\*mate\*#se',
'#\*mrcoconut\*#se',
'#\*nox\*#se',
'#\*quartermaster\*#se',
'#\*rigger\*#se',
'#\*rower\*#se',
'#\*sloth\*#se',
'#\*swabbie\*#se',
'#\*angelpuss\*#se',
'#\*feepit\*#se',
'#\*jinjah\*#se',
'#\*kadoatery\*#se',
'#\*kadoatie\*#se',
'#\*larnikin\*#se',
'#\*meepit\*#se',
'#\*mootix\*#se',
'#\*pinchit\*#se',
'#\*slorg\*#se',
'#\*warf\*#se',
'#\*weewoo\*#se',
'#\*babypb\*#se',
'#\*baf\*#se',
'#\*bdf\*#se',
'#\*bef\*#se',
'#\*bff\*#se',
'#\*bgc\*#se',
'#\*blf\*#se',
'#\*bwf\*#se',
'#\*carrot\*#se',
'#\*codestone\*#se',
'#\*dariganpb\*#se',
'#\*dubloon\*#se',
'#\*dung\*#se',
'#\*faeriepb\*#se',
'#\*mspp\*#se',
'#\*piratepb\*#se',
'#\*sock\*#se',
'#\*suap\*#se',
'#\*catfish\*#se',
'#\*star\*#se',
'#\*swagbag\*#se',
'#\*0.o.0\*#se',
'#\*bauble\*#se',
'#\*flower\*#se',
'#\*ghost\*#se',
'#\*holly\*#se',
'#\*mistletoe\*#se',
'#\*present\*#se',
'#\*pumpkin\*#se',
'#\*rednose\*#se',
'#\*santa\*#se',
'#\*snowflake\*#se',
'#\*snowman\*#se',
'#\*tombstone\*#se',
'#\*witch\*#se',
'#\*xmastree\*#se',
'#\*altador\*#se',
'#\*brightvale\*#se',
'#\*darigan\*#se',
'#\*faerieland\*#se',
'#\*hauntedwoods\*#se',
'#\*kikolake\*#se',
'#\*krawkisland\*#se',
'#\*kreludor\*#se',
'#\*lostdesert\*#se',
'#\*maraqua\*#se',
'#\*meridell\*#se',
'#\*moltara\*#se',
'#\*mysteryisland\*#se',
'#\*rooisland\*#se',
'#\*shenkuu\*#se',
'#\*terrormountain\*#se',
'#\*tyrannia\*#se',
'#\*virtupets\*#se',
'#\*angry\*#se',
'#\*clap\*#se',
'#\*complain\*#se',
'#\*cough\*#se',
'#\*cry\*#se',
'#\*facepalm\*#se',
'#\*lol\*#se',
'#\*unsure\*#se',
'#\*violin\*#se',
'#\*yarr\*#se',
'#:\)#se',
'#;\)#se',
'#:\(#se',
'#:\*#se',
'#:D#se',
'#:K#se',
'#:o#se',
'#:P#se',
'#B\)#se',
'#0:\-\)#se',
'#\*snowager\*#se',
'#\*turmaculus\*#se',
); //codes used in posts 
$replace = array( 
"'<sup>'", 
"'</sup>'", 
"''", 
"'<p>'", 
"'</p>'", 
"'<br>'", 
"'</br>'", 
"'<b>'", 
"'</b>'", 
"'<i>'", 
"'</i>'", 
"'<u>'", 
"'</u>'", 
"'<p style=\"text-align:left;\">'", 
"'</p>'", 
"'<p style=\"text-align:right;\">'", 
"'</p>'", 
"'<center>'", 
"'</center>'", 
"'</font>'", 
"'<font color=\'\\1\' size=\'\\2\' face=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font color=\'\\1\' face=\'\\2\' size=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font size=\'\\1\' color=\'\\2\' face=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font size=\'\\1\' face=\'\\2\' color=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font face=\'\\1\' color=\'\\2\' size=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font face=\'\\1\' size=\'\\2\' color=\'\\3\'>'",
"'<font color=\'\\1\' face=\'\\2\'>'",
"'<font color=\'\\1\' size=\'\\2\'>'",
"'<font size=\'\\1\' face=\'\\2\'>'",
"'<font size=\'\\1\' color=\'\\2\'>'",
"'<font size=\'\\1\'>'",
"'<font face=\'\\1\'>'",
"'<font color=\'\\1\'>'",
"' '",
"' '",
"'This is how your post will look on the Neoboards.'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/acara.gif\' >'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/aisha.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/blumaroo.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bori.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bruce.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/buzz.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/chia.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/cybunny.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/draik.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/eyrie.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/flotsam.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/gelert.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/gnorbu.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/grundo.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/hissi.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/jubjub.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kacheek.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kau.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kiko.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/korbat.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kougra.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/krawk.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kyrii.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/lenny.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/lupe.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/SketchedNeo.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/meerca.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/ogrin.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/poogle.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/pteri.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/ruki.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/scorchio.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/shoyru.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/techo.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/tonu.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/usul.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/wocky.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/xweetok.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/yurble.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/zafara.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/candycane.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/aaa.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/abigail.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/boatswain.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/cabinboy.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/coltzan.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/cook.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/gunner.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/hanso.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/happinessfaerie.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/illusen.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/jazan.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/jhudora.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/lulu.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mate.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mrcoconut.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/nox.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/quartermaster.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/rigger.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/rower.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/sloth.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/swabbie.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/angelpuss.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/feepit.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/jinjah.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kadoatery.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kadoatie.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/larnikin.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/meepit.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mootix.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/pinchit.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/slorg.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/warf.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/weewoo.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/babypb.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/baf.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bdf.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bef.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bff.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bgc.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/blf.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bwf.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/carrot.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/codestone.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/dariganpb.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/dubloon.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/dung.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/faeriepb.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mspp.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/piratepb.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/sock.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/suap.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/catfish.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/star.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/swagbag.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/0.o.0.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/bauble.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/flower.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/ghost.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/holly.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mistletoe.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/present.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/pumpkin.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/rednose.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/santa.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/snowflake.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/snowman.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/tombstone.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/witchhat.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/xmastree.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/altador.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/brightvale.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/darigan.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/faerieland.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/hauntedwoods.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kikolake.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/krawkisland.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kreludor.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/lostdesert.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/maraqua.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/meridell.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/moltara.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/mysteryisland.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/rooisland.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/shenkuu.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/terrormountain.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/tyrannia.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/virtupets.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/angry.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/clap.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/complain.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/cough.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/cry.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/facepalm.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/lol.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/unsure.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/violin.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/yarr.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/smileys/smiley.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/winking.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/sad.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/kisskiss.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/grin.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/vampire.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/oh.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/tongue.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/sunglasses.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/angel.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/snowager.gif\' \>'",
"'<img src=\'http://images.neopets.com/neoboards/smilies/turmaculus.gif\' \>'",
); //replacements 
return preg_replace($match, $replace, $content); //match, and replace 
} //end the function 
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks broken by design, use a bbcode parser instead. regex aren't helpful and you can't expect much debugging help here for such a tedious task. See: [Best way to parse bbcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.. Is there a direction you can point me.. to learn bbcode parser?

Comment: you have used a `\>` to close your image tags it actually a forward slash `/>`