# RegEx with optional part inside

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty new to regular expression. Just tried to analyse a "BB-Code" that could do something like this:

---

Pattern:

```
\[element title=(.*)picture=(\d+)](.*)(?:\[caption](.*):?\[/caption])?\[/caption].*
```

---

Search:

> [element title=element title picture=32]Lorem ipsum dolor[caption]Photo by John Doe[/caption][/element]
>
> [element title=element title picture=32]Lorem ipsum dolor[/element]

---

Well, the caption-part should be optional and both entries should give results. How can I reach this?

Comment: Is the caption always at the end, immediately before `[/element]` ?

Comment: yes, the caption is always immediately before [/element] - if a caption is given.

Comment: Check here how to parse BBCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
\[element title=(.*)picture=(\d+)\](.*?)(\[caption\](.*)\[/caption\])?\[/element\]
```

It will match both:

```
[element title=element title picture=32]Lorem ipsum dolor[caption]Photo by John Doe[/caption][/element]

[element title=element title picture=32]Lorem ipsum dolor[/element]
```

### Example

in PHP, you can use it this way:

```
$regex = '#\[element title=(.*)picture=(\d+)\](.*?)(\[caption\](.*)\[/caption\])?\[/element\]#i';
$text = '[element title=element title picture=32]Lorem ipsum dolor[caption]Photo by John Doe[/caption][/element]';    

preg_match ( $regex, $text, $match );

print_r( $match );
```

The array `$match` will have several elements. Those are the strings that are surrounded by round-brackets `(` and `)` in the regular expression. One of them is the caption text.

Program execution and output can be seen here  [`http://ideone.com/vQ1T0`](http://ideone.com/vQ1T0).

Comment: you're right, both matches. but how to extract the "caption" in a group if available?

Comment: @snuffer.ch: what language are you using? PHP?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP - Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\[element title=(.*) picture=[0-9]+\](.*)(\[caption\](.)*\[\caption\])?\[/element\]
```